# Getting error 400 trying to upload a cropped image using fetch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fetch-api, form-data, imgur

I am a newbie to JavaScript. I am trying to implement a feature to my website that allows the user to upload an image, crop the image, then press a button to upload the cropped image to imgur through the Imgur API. I am able to get the following code to work when I apply it directly to the "upload file" button, before the user crops the image. But when I try to apply it to the "upload to imgur" button, I get error 400. I hope I explained that well. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be? In this code, 'up' represents the button to upload the file to imgur, and 'cropped' represents the cropped image.

```js
up.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("image", cropped);
  fetch("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Client-ID <client ID>",
    },
    body: formdata,
  })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => {
      img_result.src = data.data.link;
      document.getElementById("url").innerText = data.data.link;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In particular, include your HTML buttons and form (if you have one)

Comment: Please, open console of your browser and post the response from imgur API. It might even answer your question. The problem is in your `formdata` contents.

Comment: What documentation are you following? There is no `POST /3/image/` endpoint. The [upload endpoint](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139) is `POST /3/upload`. _Edit_ ok, their documentation is super confusing. The docs say `/3/upload` but the examples use `/3/image`. In any case, none of them end in a trailing `/`

Comment: Please add **all** the relevant code ( no sensitive data though ) ~ as it is presently there are too many unknowns